# can't find python debug console in blender 2.7.6

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to debug a Python script by placing `print( "hello")` statements in my code.

But where does the output appear?

It doesn't appear on the Python Console, there is no option for 'Window > Toggle System Console.'

I am using blender 2.7.6 and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: you need to start blender from a terminal